# UIActionSheet delegate method doesn't get called

Tags: iphone, ios, uiactionsheet

I have an actionsheet that seems to only call the clickedButtonAtIndex delegate method when I click the "Yes" button, but not on the "No" button...  Here's the code:

```
self.myActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test" delegate:self
      cancelButtonTitle:@"No" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Yes" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[self.myActionSheet showInView:self.view];
[myActionSheet release];
```

then the delegate method:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)myActionSheet
     clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        [self.myActionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:YES];
        return;
    }
```

My breakpoint at the first line of this procedure doesn't get hit unless I touch the
"Yes" button.  I have changed this to have the cancelButtonTitle:nil and then put the "No" on another button (otherButtonTitles:@"No", nil).  Same thing.

Any help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try touching the very top of the No button. Does it work?

Do you have a tab bar or a tool bar? If so, try showing the action sheet from the tab bar or the tool bar. The No button could be partially obscured by the bar.

Comment: OMG you're a genius Terry....  Yes, I do have a tab bar.  Is this a bug?  Any suggestion on how to get around this?

Comment: Use showFromTabBar. That will put the sheet in the right place to get all the touches.

Comment: I always make this same mistake :)

Comment: I've made it multiple times. That's why I know which questions to ask.

Answer (score 1):

No, its not a bug.. just a "Real Estate" issue. 
take a look at the API.. from the UIActionSheet header...

```
// show a sheet animated. you can specify either a toolbar, a tab bar, a bar butto item or a plain view. We do a special animation if the sheet rises from
// a toolbar, tab bar or bar button item and we will automatically select the correct style based on the bar style. if not from a bar, we use
// UIActionSheetStyleDefault if automatic style set
- (void)showFromToolbar:(UIToolbar *)view;
- (void)showFromTabBar:(UITabBar *)view;
- (void)showFromBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)item animated:(BOOL)animated __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_3_2);
- (void)showFromRect:(CGRect)rect inView:(UIView *)view animated:(BOOL)animated __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_3_2);
- (void)showInView:(UIView *)view;
```